# Flutter how to mock function response when it is called in tested function

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, mocking

I am trying to test some api call function:

```
  Future<SomeType> getType(int id) async {
    String token = await retrieveToken();
    String api = await getApiEndpoint();
    final response = await client.get("$api/something/$id", headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer $token"});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String body = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
      return SomeType.fromJson(json.decode(body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load some types from API');
    }
  }
```

The two functions:

```
retrieveToken();
getApiEndpoint();
```

that are called inside are not members of the same class as getType() function. They also contain
inside them instances of FlutterSecureStorage().

I don't need to test this function, I just want to mock their responses in the test of getType function.

I've created following test example:

```
class MockedApiEndpoint extends Mock implements ApiEndpoint {}
void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    test('returns SomeType', () async {
      final typesRepository = TypesRepository();
      final mockedApiEndpoint = MockedApiEndpoint();

      when(mockedApiEndpoint.getApiEndpoint()).thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value("some_url.com"));
      when(mockedApiEndpoint.retrieveToken()).thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value("some_token"));

      typesRepository.client = MockClient( (request) async {
        final mapJson = {'id' : 123};
        return Response(json.encode(mapJson), 200);
      });

      final type =  await typesRepository.getType(123);
      expect(type.id, 123);
    });
}
```

I was able to succesfully Mock the client reposne, I am also trying to mock responses of those two functions, but I am constantly receiveing following error:

**MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method read on channel plugins.it_nomads.com/flutter_secure_storage)**

I would be very greatful for any hints how to approach this topic and what I am doing wrong with this one. I am new to unit testing in Flutter, I've tried to find any similar problem to mine on the web but unfortunatelly failed.

Answer (score 0):

The ApiEndPoint class must be passed to the TypesRepository class as a dependency. Then in the test you pass the instantiated mock in the constructor, otherwise dart doesn't know which instance you are referring to with the mock you are making, which is the error it is returning.

```
class TypesRepository{
  final ApiEndpoint apiEndpoint;

  TypesRepository(this.apiEndpoint);
...
}
```

```
class MockedApiEndpoint extends Mock implements ApiEndpoint {}
void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    test('returns SomeType', () async {
      final ApiEndPoint mockedApiEndpoint = MockedApiEndpoint();
      final typesRepository = TypesRepository(mockedApiEndpoint);

      when(mockedApiEndpoint.getApiEndpoint()).thenAnswer((_) async => "some_url.com");
      when(mockedApiEndpoint.retrieveToken()).thenAnswer((_) async => ("some_token");

      typesRepository.client = MockClient( (request) async {
        final mapJson = {'id' : 123};
        return Response(json.encode(mapJson), 200);
      });

      final type =  await typesRepository.getType(123);
      expect(type.id, 123);
    });
}
```